# How can I modify my program to return the same output if a single number is inputted?

Tags: python, list, function, integer

So I'm trying to create a program to find all the permutations of every number within `1 to n`

So for instance if n = 5, so basically we must find the permutations for [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and for instance if n = 3, we must find the permutations for [1, 2, 3]. The output must be returned as a tuple.

So now I have this code that returns the permutations **if the input is a list only**  and it works.. but how can I modify it to return all permutations when `n: int` is the input...

```
def permutation(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]
    l = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        m = lst[i]
        remLst = lst[:i] + lst[i + 1:]
        for p in permutation(remLst):
            l.append([m] + p)
    return l
```

What changes should I make for my code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) built-in function:

```
def permutation(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, int):
        lst = list(range(1, lst + 1))
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]
    l = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        m = lst[i]
        remLst = lst[:i] + lst[i + 1:]
        for p in permutation(remLst):
            l.append(tuple([m] + list(p)))
    return tuple(l)
```

Now both integer and list arguments should work:

```
print(permutation(3))
```

or

```
print(permutation([1, 3, 5]))
```

Comment: Thank u for ur response, but how can I return this as a tuple like (x,x),(x,x) though? can I just write return (tuple(l)) in the last line?

Comment: For that, a `return tuple(l)` should suffice. For a tuple of tuples see my updated answer.